# SIM shows no service most of the time

Tags: iphone, sim

I’m using BSNL SIM which shows no service most of the time on my iPhone SE 2022 model. But the SIM works perfectly on Android phones. I contacted their support but no solution was given since the issue was only on iPhone. Please note other sims works perfectly on iPhone. It’s a 4G SIM. Now I’m forced to use Android because of this.

Comment: This is between you and your provider. SIM cards offer no user-customisable options. The only possibility is that the SIM contacts in the phone are dirty; but if the SIM is always recognised, yet service occasionally drops, then that's not the answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin other sims works perfectly on iphone.

Comment: Then ask your provider for a new SIM. They're usually free - they give them out like candy. SIM firmware does change over time, to match new phone standards.